# AWS Lambda node-soap function (serverless framework)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, node-soap

I am testing a call to a SOAP service using node-soap library.
This works fine as a standalone node.js app and the SOAP service responds, however when I package the same code up as a serverless AWS lambda function (using serverless framework, but also executed directly in AWS lambda), it doesn’t appear to create the soap client.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

```
export async function main(event, context) {
    var soap = require('soap');
    var url = 'https://service.blah.co.uk/Service/Function.asmx?wsdl';

    var soapOptions = {
        forceSoap12Headers: true
    };

    var soapHeader = {
        'SOAPAction': 'http://www.blah.co.uk/Services/GetToken'
    };

    var params = {
        xmlMessage: message
    };

    console.log(JSON.stringify(params));

    soap.createClient(url, soapOptions, function (err, client) {
        //the serverless AWS lambda function never reaches this point (deployed and invoked locally)

        console.log("In create client")
        if (err) console.log(err);
        client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);
        client.GetToken(params, function (err, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I have tested it locally and the code inside soap.createClient() never executes.

Comment: I have added a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a very minimal working example using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await). Rather using the old style callback approach, just invoke soap.createClientAsync(url).

Here's the code:

```
'use strict';
const soap = require('soap');
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {

    const url = 'http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl';

    const client = await soap.createClientAsync(url)

    console.log(client)

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'It works!'
    }
}
```

And here are the logs (partially):

[image]

**EDIT**: Function's output (via AWS's Lambda Console)

[image]

**EDIT 2 - The REAL problem**

Check the link above around async/await. The async keyword will execute asynchronously and will return a Promise. Since it's an asynchronous function, your Lambda is being terminated before it could actually execute your callback.

Using async/await will make your code simpler and will have you stop beating your brains out for such a small thing like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - this resolved my issue. I'll also incorporate your suggestion about async/await.